# How to process latest record corresponding to a key in given time frame in kafka streams?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, apache-kafka-streams, spring-kafka, kafka-producer-api

Explanation: I want to process only the latest unique event for a key. I have KafkaStreams<String,LocationChangeEvent> kstreams. Suppose I got these events in kafkaStreams :

```
{id= "DELHI", event1},
{id= "MUMBAI", event2},
{id= "DELHI", event3},
{id= "JAIPUR", event4},
{id= "MUMBAI", event5}
```

Now, I want to group them (say in 10 minutes), so that I only have latest event for every key within given time frame.

```
`**EXPECTED EVENTS:**{id= "DELHI", event3},
                     {id= "MUMBAI", event5},
                     {id= "JAIPUR", event4}`



 **Events output according to my code implementation :** 
            {id= "DELHI", event1},
            {id= "MUMBAI", event2},
            {id= "JAIPUR", event4} and rest are marked as duplicated.
```

According to code attached below, I am able to push first unique event to consumer and further mark all event with same key as duplicate in given time. But I don't want to send first event rather I want to send the latest event for every key i.e last event for every key in that time frame.

```
Properties streamsConfiguration = this.buildKafkaProperties();
                         StreamsBuilder builder = new StreamsBuilder(); KStream<String, LocationChangeEvent> kStream = builder.stream(this.kafkaConfigProperties.getTopicName(), Consumed.with(Serdes.String(), locationChangeEventSerde));
                            final StoreBuilder<WindowStore<String, LocationChangeEvent>> dedupStoreBuilder = Stores.windowStoreBuilder(
                                        Stores.persistentWindowStore(storeName, retentionPeriod, numSegment, minutes, false),
                                        Serdes.String(),
                                        serde);
                                    builder.addStateStore(dedupStoreBuilder);
                                    kStream.filter((key,value)->value.getChangeId()!=null)
                                        .transformValues(() -> new DeduplicationTransformer<>(windowSize.toMillis(), (key, value) -> key), storeName)
                                        .filter((k, v) -> v != null)
                                        .foreach((requestId, object) -> {
                                                    // below function push event to consumer
                                                     this.streamKafkaFunction(object);
                                        });
                            KafkaStreams streams = new KafkaStreams(builder.build(), streamsConfiguration);
                                    streams.start();
                    }
                 private static class DeduplicationTransformer<K, V, E> implements ValueTransformerWithKey<K, V, V> {
                            private ProcessorContext context;
                            private WindowStore<E, Long> eventIdStore;
                            private final long leftDurationMs;
                            private final long rightDurationMs;
                            private final KeyValueMapper<K, V, E> idExtractor;
                    DeduplicationTransformer(final long maintainDurationPerEventInMs, final KeyValueMapper<K, V, E> idExtractor) {
                                if (maintainDurationPerEventInMs < 1) {
                                    throw new IllegalArgumentException("maintain duration per event must be >= 1");
                                }
                                leftDurationMs = maintainDurationPerEventInMs;
                                rightDurationMs = maintainDurationPerEventInMs;
                                this.idExtractor = idExtractor;
                            }
                    
                            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
                            @Override
                            public void init(ProcessorContext context) {
                                this.context = context;
                                eventIdStore = (WindowStore<E, Long>) 
                                context.getStateStore(storeName);
                            }
                        @Override
                            public V transform(final K key, final V value) {
                                final E eventId = idExtractor.apply(key, value);
                                LOGGER.info("Event is : {}", eventId);
                                if (eventId == null) {
                                    return value;
                                } else {
                                    final V output;
                                    if (isDuplicate(eventId)) {
                                        output = null;
                                    } else {
                                        output = value;
                                        rememberNewEvent(eventId, context.timestamp());
                                    }
                                    return output;
                                }
                            }
                    private boolean isDuplicate(final E eventId) {
                                final long eventTime = context.timestamp();
                                final WindowStoreIterator<Long> timeIterator = eventIdStore.fetch(
                                    eventId,
                                    eventTime - leftDurationMs,
                                    eventTime + rightDurationMs);
                                final boolean isDuplicate = timeIterator.hasNext();
                                timeIterator.close();
                                return isDuplicate;
                            }
    
                            private void rememberNewEvent(final E eventId, final long timestamp) {
                                eventIdStore.put(eventId, timestamp, timestamp);
                            }
    
                    @Override
                            public void close() {
                            }
                        }
```

Comment: you should maybe use an aggregate function on a window (to only keep teh last value for each key) and then use the delete operation to only send the last event for each key-window

Comment: Can you please explain using code ?

Comment: Can you please elaborate using code ?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple example showing how to use Windowded Aggregation with the `suppress` operation to only emit the last received value for each key only when the window is closed;

```java
        var builder = new StreamsBuilder();
        builder.stream("my-input topic")
               .groupByKey()
               .windowedBy(TimeWindows.of(Duration.ofMinutes(10)))
               .reduce((value1, value2) -> value2)
               .suppress(Suppressed.untilWindowCloses(Suppressed.BufferConfig.unbounded()))
               .toStream()
               .to("my-output-topic");
```

Note: You should consider to use a grace period if you have to tolerate out-of-order events, i.e.,using  `TimeWindows.of(Duration.ofMinutes(10)).grace(Duration.ofMinutes(1))`

Comment: Is it necassary to consume with another topic ? and How can I iterate over kafka Streams (key,value) to call my function.(foreach((requestId, object) -> {
                                                    // below function push event to consumer
                                                     this.streamKafkaFunction(object);
                                        });) as in above code

Comment: The important part are the windowed/reduce and suppress methods. After that you can do whatever you want. Note, it is usually highly recommand to push results into an output topic to achieve exactly_once.

Comment: How can I read from that output topic(I need to call that function mentioned in above comment) ? Please help as I am new to Kafka.

Comment: Not getting events even after pushing results to different topic. I am processing the events from output topic in the same class.        kStream
   .groupByKey()
   .windowedBy(TimeWindows.of(Duration.ofMinutes(2)))
   .reduce((value1, value2) -> value2)
   .suppress(Suppressed.untilWindowCloses(Suppressed.BufferConfig.unbounded()))
   .toStream()
   .to("stream-dedup1");

  KStream<String, LocationChangeEvent> stream_1 = builder.stream("stream-dedup1");
  stream_1.foreach((key,object)->{
   this.streamKafkaFunction(object);
  });      @fhussonnois please help.